# Async.js filtering an array not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am trying to use async's filter method but I am not getting the result I expect

```
async.filter([1, 3, 5], function (item, done) {
        done(item > 1);
    }, function (results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
    async.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(item, callback) {
      if (item > 3) {
          callback(true);
      } else {
        callback(false);
      }

    },
    function (result) {
      console.log("result: " + result);
    });
```

the output is

> true
>
> result: true

and not 2 filtered arrays, what am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should use a bit different syntax, like it specified here: [async#filter](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#filter)

The result in a callback should be a second parameter(not a first one): `callback(null, true)`

For example:

```
async.filter([1, 3, 5], function (item, done) {
    done(null, item > 1);
}, function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
async.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(item, callback) {
  if (item > 3) {
      callback(null, true);
  } else {
    callback(false);
  }

},
function (err, result) {
  console.log("result: " + result);
});
```

[jsbin#example](https://jsbin.com/boyoqabipu/edit?js,output)